# Are graphs of derivatives connected?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, derivatives, connectedness

One of the basis results in real analysis is the Darboux's theorem, which says the derivative of a differentiable function has the intermediate value property.

I've always been a bit dissatistied with this result as I think the following stronger result holds:

> Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be a differentiable function, then the graph of $f'$ is connected.

Is there a proof of this statement?

(differentiable on $[a,b]$ means differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $f'_+(a)$, $f'_-(b)$ exist)

Answer (score 4):

I believe I have some references that you can use to cobble together a proof.

According to [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_function), the derivative of any differentiable function is of Baire class 1.

Theorem 4.1 in [this paper](https://eudml.org/doc/146526) by Bruckner, Ceder (1965) (page 99) proves that every Darboux function of Baire class 1 has a connected graph.

As you have stated, we already know that the derivative is a Darboux function.

I'm not overly familliar with these concepts myself, so I can't vouch for the validity, say, the wiki claim, but this certainly should be a line of inquiry worth investigating.

Comment: Nice find! It seems like a possible way. I'll leave this open for now in case someone wants to explain this in detail or finds a direct way. I'm also not too familiar with these concepts.

Comment: Sure. I might try to read through some of this material and produce a synthesis later, if I find time, as these concepts are semi-related to a course that I'm currently taking.